# Group, Project, Aggregation, Sort, MongoDB Query to Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, database, mongodb

I want to group by below mongo collection.
Group by for year and month. and I want to populate the below java class as a list. I tried many ways could not find the relevant article so I'm publishing problem here,

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "620f09ff8ed7d86747d45344"
  },
  "user_id": "620f09808ed7d86747d4533f",
  "price": 351,
  "created_time": {
    "$date": "2021-12-18T02:52:47.837Z"
  },
  "orderItem": [
    {
      "bookId": "620e02dacc3e1d31bd8deb54",
      "qty": 1,
      "unitPrice": 101
    },
    {
      "bookId": "620f033cb4e4494aff6ef56c",
      "qty": 1,
      "unitPrice": 250
    }
  ],
  "_class": "com.code.onlinebookstoreservice.entity.Order"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "620f57e0e7d4cf6156c16682"
  },
  "user_id": "620f09b98ed7d86747d45343",
  "price": 610,
  "created_time": {
    "$date": "2022-01-18T08:25:04.569Z"
  },
  "orderItem": [
    {
      "bookId": "620f0313b4e4494aff6ef56b",
      "qty": 1,
      "unitPrice": 150
    },
    {
      "bookId": "620f0347b4e4494aff6ef56d",
      "qty": 2,
      "unitPrice": 230
    }
  ],
  "_class": "com.code.onlinebookstoreservice.entity.Order"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "620f58aafde9e82682d5a725"
  },
  "user_id": "620f09b98ed7d86747d45343",
  "price": 380,
  "created_time": {
    "$date": "2022-02-18T08:28:26.483Z"
  },
  "orderItem": [
    {
      "bookId": "620f0313b4e4494aff6ef56b",
      "qty": 1,
      "unitPrice": 150
    },
    {
      "bookId": "620f0347b4e4494aff6ef56d",
      "qty": 1,
      "unitPrice": 230
    }
  ],
  "_class": "com.code.onlinebookstoreservice.entity.Order"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "620fb8ead2463f3c44d87108"
  },
  "user_id": "620f09b98ed7d86747d45343",
  "price": 380,
  "created_time": {
    "$date": "2022-01-18T15:19:06.938Z"
  },
  "orderItem": [
    {
      "bookId": "620f0313b4e4494aff6ef56b",
      "qty": 1,
      "unitPrice": 150
    },
    {
      "bookId": "620f0347b4e4494aff6ef56d",
      "qty": 1,
      "unitPrice": 230
    }
  ],
  "_class": "com.code.onlinebookstoreservice.entity.Order"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "620fb8ebd2463f3c44d87109"
  },
  "user_id": "620f09b98ed7d86747d45343",
  "price": 380,
  "created_time": {
    "$date": "2021-12-18T15:19:07.829Z"
  },
  "orderItem": [
    {
      "bookId": "620f0313b4e4494aff6ef56b",
      "qty": 1,
      "unitPrice": 150
    },
    {
      "bookId": "620f0347b4e4494aff6ef56d",
      "qty": 1,
      "unitPrice": 230
    }
  ],
  "_class": "com.code.onlinebookstoreservice.entity.Order"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "620fb8ecd2463f3c44d8710a"
  },
  "user_id": "620f09b98ed7d86747d45343",
  "price": 380,
  "created_time": {
    "$date": "2022-01-18T15:19:08.575Z"
  },
  "orderItem": [
    {
      "bookId": "620f0313b4e4494aff6ef56b",
      "qty": 1,
      "unitPrice": 150
    },
    {
      "bookId": "620f0347b4e4494aff6ef56d",
      "qty": 1,
      "unitPrice": 230
    }
  ],
  "_class": "com.code.onlinebookstoreservice.entity.Order"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "620fb8edd2463f3c44d8710b"
  },
  "user_id": "620f09b98ed7d86747d45343",
  "price": 380,
  "created_time": {
    "$date": "2022-02-18T15:19:09.269Z"
  },
  "orderItem": [
    {
      "bookId": "620f0313b4e4494aff6ef56b",
      "qty": 1,
      "unitPrice": 150
    },
    {
      "bookId": "620f0347b4e4494aff6ef56d",
      "qty": 1,
      "unitPrice": 230
    }
  ],
  "_class": "com.code.onlinebookstoreservice.entity.Order"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "620fb8edd2463f3c44d8710c"
  },
  "user_id": "620f09b98ed7d86747d45343",
  "price": 380,
  "created_time": {
    "$date": "2022-02-18T15:19:09.867Z"
  },
  "orderItem": [
    {
      "bookId": "620f0313b4e4494aff6ef56b",
      "qty": 1,
      "unitPrice": 150
    },
    {
      "bookId": "620f0347b4e4494aff6ef56d",
      "qty": 1,
      "unitPrice": 230
    }
  ],
  "_class": "com.code.onlinebookstoreservice.entity.Order"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "620fb8eed2463f3c44d8710d"
  },
  "user_id": "620f09b98ed7d86747d45343",
  "price": 380,
  "created_time": {
    "$date": "2022-02-18T15:19:10.374Z"
  },
  "orderItem": [
    {
      "bookId": "620f0313b4e4494aff6ef56b",
      "qty": 1,
      "unitPrice": 150
    },
    {
      "bookId": "620f0347b4e4494aff6ef56d",
      "qty": 1,
      "unitPrice": 230
    }
  ],
  "_class": "com.code.onlinebookstoreservice.entity.Order"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "620fb8eed2463f3c44d8710e"
  },
  "user_id": "620f09b98ed7d86747d45343",
  "price": 380,
  "created_time": {
    "$date": "2022-02-18T15:19:10.785Z"
  },
  "orderItem": [
    {
      "bookId": "620f0313b4e4494aff6ef56b",
      "qty": 1,
      "unitPrice": 150
    },
    {
      "bookId": "620f0347b4e4494aff6ef56d",
      "qty": 1,
      "unitPrice": 230
    }
  ],
  "_class": "com.code.onlinebookstoreservice.entity.Order"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "620fb8f0d2463f3c44d8710f"
  },
  "user_id": "620f09b98ed7d86747d45343",
  "price": 380,
  "created_time": {
    "$date": "2022-02-18T15:19:12.250Z"
  },
  "orderItem": [
    {
      "bookId": "620f0313b4e4494aff6ef56b",
      "qty": 1,
      "unitPrice": 150
    },
    {
      "bookId": "620f0347b4e4494aff6ef56d",
      "qty": 1,
      "unitPrice": 230
    }
  ],
  "_class": "com.code.onlinebookstoreservice.entity.Order"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "620fb8f0d2463f3c44d87110"
  },
  "user_id": "620f09b98ed7d86747d45343",
  "price": 380,
  "created_time": {
    "$date": "2022-02-18T15:19:12.762Z"
  },
  "orderItem": [
    {
      "bookId": "620f0313b4e4494aff6ef56b",
      "qty": 1,
      "unitPrice": 150
    },
    {
      "bookId": "620f0347b4e4494aff6ef56d",
      "qty": 1,
      "unitPrice": 230
    }
  ],
  "_class": "com.code.onlinebookstoreservice.entity.Order"
}]
```

Finally, I was able to create a native query it is as below,

```
db.order.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      total_book_count: {
        $sum: "$orderItem.qty"
      },
      total_purches_amount: {
        "$sum": "$price"
      },
      monthly: {
        $dateToString: {
          format: "%Y-%m",
          date: "$created_time"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$monthly",
      total_order_count: {
        $count: {}
      },
      total_book_count: {
        $sum: "$total_book_count"
      },
      total_purches_amount: {
        $sum: "$total_purches_amount"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      total_order_count: -1
    }
  }
])
```

My Java Class is like below, ultimately I want this output as an array.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class StaticDto {

    private String _id;

    private Integer totalOrderCount;

    private Integer totalBookCount;

    private Integer totalPurchasedAmount;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to create a aggregation query for my problem,

```
public ResponseEntity<List<StaticDto>> getStatistics() {

    AggregationExpression totalQty = AccumulatorOperators.Sum.sumOf("orderItem.qty");
    AggregationExpression totalPrice = AccumulatorOperators.Sum.sumOf("price");

    Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
            project()
                    .and(totalQty).as("total_book_count")
                    .and(totalPrice).as("total_purchase_amount")
                    .and("created_time").dateAsFormattedString("%Y-%m").as("month"),
            group("month")
                    .count().as("totalOrderCount")
                    .sum("total_book_count").as("totalBookCount")
                    .sum("total_purchase_amount").as("totalPurchasedAmount"),
            sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "month")
    );

    AggregationResults<StaticDto> staticDtos =
            mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "order", StaticDto.class);

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(staticDtos.getMappedResults());
}
```